# JavaScript Help(It's pretty simple im a beginner)

Tags: javascript

```
function mathProb() {
    var x = parseInt(prompt("Enter first integer", ""));
    var y = parseInt(prompt("Enter the second integer", ""));
    var operand = prompt("Enter type of operation", "");

    if (operand == "+" || "add") {
        var sum = x + y;
        document.write("Your sum is " + sum);
    } else if (operand == "-") {
        var difference = x - y;
        document.write("Your difference is " + difference);
    } else if (operand == "*") {
        var product = x * y;
        document.write("Your product is " + product);
    } else if (operand == "/") {
        var quotient = x / y;
        document.write("Your quotient is " + quotient);
    } else {
        document.write("Oops something went wrong");
    }
}
```

Well to start I am reading a book on JavaScript and have been doing pretty well, I am now on functions and was getting those until parameters were introduced can someone explain what a parameter is in a clear simple way?

Why does this function work when named `function mathProb()` and `function mathProb(x,y,operand)`?

And a third question off of the previous one is why when I call the function in html
(`<input type="button" value="Calculator" onclick="mathProb()"/>`) 
I have to use `mathProb()` even if its named `mathProb(x,y,operand)`. If I call it using that name it wont work. Please help?

Comment: Please try to summarize your qeustion in the title in order to make it more descriptive of the issue.

Answer (score 1):

First, the line:

```
if(operand=="+"||"add")
```

Will always be *true*, as the expression `"add"` will always return a true-ish value.  You probably mean to use:

```
if(operand=="+" || operand=="add")
```

Your question about parameters is probably a pretty broad topic.  Basically, a parameter is a variable *given* to a function so that the function can be generalized to work with any data.  For example, if you wanted to write a function that can add two numbers, the function must know *which* two numbers to add.  These numbers would be supplied as parameters:

```
function add(x, y)
{
   return x + y; // x and y are variables known within this function
}
```

You'd then call your function as so:

```
var oneplusone = add(1, 1); // Adds 1 and 1
```

Using this knowledge, you could rewrite your code as this:

```
function mathProb(x, y, operand)
{
   // No need for var x, etc as these can now be passed in..
}
```

Then call your function:

```
mathProb(
   parseInt(prompt("Enter first integer","")), // This is x
   parseInt(prompt("Enter the second integer","")), // This is y
   prompt("Enter type of operation","") // This is operand
);
```

Keep in mind you could *still* call your function `mathProb` without the parameters:

```
mathProb();
```

...if you really wanted to.  JavaScript *does* allow this (unlike many other languages).  However, within your function, the variables `x`, `y` and `operand` will be *undefined* which might cause unexpected results if you don't account for that.

Answer (score 0):

You need call and pass function like `mathProb(1,2,'+')`

HTML:

```
 <input type="button" value="Calculator" onclick="mathProb(1,2,'+')"/>
```

Javacript:

```
function mathProb(x,y,operand)
{
    //var x = parseInt(prompt("Enter first integer",""));
    //var y = parseInt(prompt("Enter the second integer",""));
    //var operand = prompt("Enter type of operation","");

    if(operand=="+"|| operand=="add")
    {
        var sum = x+y;
        document.write("Your sum is " +sum);
    }
    else if(operand=="-")
    {
        var difference = x-y;
        document.write("Your difference is " +difference);
    }
    else if(operand=="*")
    {
        var product = x*y;
        document.write("Your product is " +product);
    }
    else if(operand=="/")
    {
        var quotient = x/y;
        document.write("Your quotient is " +quotient);
    }
    else
    {
        document.write("Oops something went wrong");
    }
}
```